# Open new thread after completion of printing line and continue until the end of the text file

Tags: python, multithreading, loops, printing

This code works well, it currently opens 3 threads and on completion of printing each line of the text file (to line 3), finishes.

But I would like it to continue and once each thread has printed a line, automatically open a new thread and continue printing each line of the text file until completion.

```
import threading
import time

def test_logic(file): # ***Changed this function***

     line = myfile.readline()
     print(line)

N = 3 
thread_list = list()
myfile = open("prox.txt", 'r') # ***Opened file at the begining***
# Start test
for i in range(N):
    t = threading.Thread(args=(myfile,), name='Test {}'.format(i), target=test_logic) # ***Passed file as an argument***
    t.start()
    time.sleep(1)
    print ("t.name +  started!")

    thread_list.append(t)

# Wait for all threads to complete
for thread in thread_list:
    thread.join()

print("Test completed!")
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this, you want to run a thread for each line. The code spawns a thread for each line in a file and then prints it. Be careful, your code doesn't have a myfile.close() at the end.

```
import time
import threading

def test_logic(line): # ***Changed this function***
     print(line)

thread_list = list()
myfile = open("prox.txt", 'r') # ***Opened file at the begining***
# Start test
file = myfile.read()
content = file.split("\n")
for i in content:
    t = threading.Thread(args=(i,), name='Test {}'.format(i), target=test_logic) # ***Passed file as an argument***
    t.start()
    time.sleep(1)
    print ("t.name +  started!")

    thread_list.append(t)

# Wait for all threads to complete
for thread in thread_list:
    thread.join()

print("Test completed!")
myfile.close()
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply. Any Idea how I would do this with 3 threads at a time, so open three threads and upon completion of each any given thread, open a new one and continue to do so but only a maximum of three threads running at one time. Thanks

Comment: I would look at Queue and managing the number of concurrent threads.